# VBA hide rows with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need help to hide rows if (will use rows 148-149 as example):

If Either J OR P 148 have a value >0 and both J AND P 149 =0 THEN 149 should hide.

IF either J OR P 149 >0 THEN BOTH 148 AND 149 should show

IF value >0 in J OR P 148 AND J OR P 149 >0 then show 148 AND 149

[image: Example]

[image: This should be the final result]

```
    Sub Skjul_0_Storkundeaftale()
 Dim beginRow As Long, endRow As Long, CheckCol_1 As Long, rngHide As Range
  beginRow = 148 'first row'
  endRow = 176 'last row'
  CheckCol_1 = 10 'column number --> O'

For rowNum = beginRow To endRow
    If Cells(rowNum, CheckCol_1).Value <= 0 And Cells(rowNum + 1, CheckCol_1).Value = "" Then
        Cells(rowNum, CheckCol_1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next rowNum
End Sub
```

Comment: Which of the two line should be considered a headline ? "Undtagelse:"? Without your 'explanations', I would think that the bold one should be...

Comment: You are right. Row 148, 151, 154, 157 are headlines.

Comment: And must be hidden only the rows below the headlines? In some circumstances... The ones having having "Undtagelse:" somewhere to the left? If yes, it would be good to tell us what column is that. And do you have hidden columns between J and P columns? It is very difficult to understand too much from your example picture... I would be good to have also the column headers in the picture.

Comment: `CheckCol_1` looks to be column P:P, but the column manually marked with "J" doesn't be also checked according to your question?

Comment: Row 148-149: 
If J148 OR P148 = <=0 AND J149 OR P149 <= 0 then hide Row 148-149
OR J149 OR P149 =>0 then show row 148 AND 149.

Comment: I do not understand anything, sorry... Can you post, at least, a picture with the situation as you need? The resulted situation. I can stay in my office not more the 15 min. If I can see it, i can try helping you. Otherwise, I cannot understand what is to be done...

Comment: Let me update the code because I almost go it to work

Comment: So, I  wish you good luck!

Comment: @FaneDuru the code you wrote almost does the job. Except one little issue. Can you take a look again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209583/discussion-between-thomasuponor-and-faneduru).

Comment: I can (now), but in order to do that, I need to understand what is to be done. It looks I understood and I created a piece of code. Then, I understood that my understanding is wrong and I delete it... I can help only if you can better explain what is to be done. I asked you to "post, at least, a picture with the situation as you need" after your first picture processing. but I do not see anything even now...

Comment: @FaneDuru Alright, I attached a picture showing the situation as I need. Cheers

Comment: Please, test the updated code and conform that it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a new code. Maybe not the best coding but it does the trick :)

```
Sub Skjul_0_Storkundeaftale()

beginRow = 148 'first row'
endRow = 176 'last row'
CheckCol_1 = 4 'column number --> Gulvarme
CheckCol_2 = 10 'First column
CheckCol_3 = 16 'Second column

For rowNum = beginRow To endRow
    If Cells(rowNum, CheckCol_1).Value <> "" And Cells(rowNum + 1, CheckCol_2).Value = 0 And Cells(rowNum + 1, CheckCol_3).Value = 0 Then
        Cells(rowNum + 1, CheckCol_1).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End If
Next rowNum

For rowNum = beginRow To endRow
    If Cells(rowNum, CheckCol_1).Value <> "" And Cells(rowNum, CheckCol_2).Value = 0 And Cells(rowNum, CheckCol_3).Value = 0 _
    And Cells(rowNum + 1, CheckCol_2).Value = 0 And Cells(rowNum + 1, CheckCol_3).Value = 0 Then
        Cells(rowNum, CheckCol_1).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End If
Next rowNum


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Wesley, can you help with similar issue. This time a new row has been added below is text with bold. So we have 2 rows instead of one.

Comment: @thomasuponor, can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub Skjul_0_Storkundeaftale()
 Dim beginRow As Long, endRow As Long, rowNum As Long
  beginRow = 148 'first row'
  endRow = 176  'last row'

 For rowNum = beginRow To endRow
    If Cells(rowNum, "P").value <= 0 Or Cells(rowNum, "J").value <= 0 Then
        If Len(Cells(rowNum, "P").value) <> 0 Then
            If Len(Cells(rowNum + 1, "P").value) <> 0 Then
                If Cells(rowNum + 1, "P").value = 0 And _
                    Cells(rowNum + 1, "J").value = 0 And _
                        Cells(rowNum + 2, "J").value = Empty Then
                    Cells(rowNum + 1, "P").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    rowNum = rowNum + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
 Next rowNum
End Sub
```

Comment: @thomasuponor: Please, test the updated code and conform that it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Skjul_0_Storkundeaftale()

beginRow = 148 'first row'
endRow = 176'last row'
CheckCol_1 = 10 'column number --> O'
CheckCol_2 = 2 ' column b

For rowNum = beginRow To endRow
    If Cells(rowNum, CheckCol_2).Value <> "" And Cells(rowNum + 1, CheckCol_1).Value = 0 Then
        Cells(rowNum, CheckCol_1).EntireRow.Hidden = True

       End If
    Next rowNum

End Sub
```

You can use something like this. You can still navigate row numbers within the brackets. So if you want to check 1 row below, you just doe rowNum + 1. 
You can also add other 'AND' of 'IF' rules to your code.

Comment: Hi, his one only seems to look into J. It hides rows also if P has values

Comment: Then I do not understand your question. So It has to be like this?
If headline J or P =0 And Headline row+1 J or P <> 0 then the headline row+1 has to hide?

Comment: I just uploaded a picture how the situation show be. Let me know if this makes more sense.

Comment: What should it do when all 4 values are 0? Because now it would just be if J or P from row+1 = 0 then hide row+1. Can you also give me the column number of "Gulvarme"

Comment: If all 4 values are 0 then hide both rows. Column number of "gulvarme" is D